# CSS Horizontal List Background Image Not Showing

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to add a background image to a simple horizontal list and for some reason, I am unable to get it to show. This is a static HTML/CSS practice page that can be viewed @ [DropBox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15447938/BillDueDate/index.html)

Here is my HTML markup

```
<section class="welcome-msg">
            <p>Good Morning</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Edit Bill</li>
                <li>Mark Bill as Paid</li>
                <li>Bill Details</li>
                <li>Help</li>
            </ul>

</section>
```

And here is the CSS

```
.welcome-msg li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px; 
    background-image: url(Image/details-icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*background-position:5px 0px;*/
}
```

And here is the [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15447938/BillDueDate/Mock/Screenshot.JPG) of the image folder

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/9RWnT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You image folder isn't in the same folder as your CSS file.

```html
  -CSS
  --style.css
  -Images
  --img.png
  --img2.png
```

You therefore need to go a level up first (out of the css folder) and then into the `Image` directory. This is achieved by using `../` at the beginning of the path.

Therefore your URI should be:

```
 background-image: url(../Image/details-icon.png);
```

Comment: Wow, that was it. Interesting, It never occurred to me that I have to go up since the html page and the Image folder are on the same level.

Comment: always the image should be relative to the css path!!

Answer (score 1):

Please use developer console (F12) for debugging.

[image]

Problem with incorrect path.

```
background-image: url(../Image/details-icon.png);
```

Comment: Thanks, learning something everyday, I will make sure to check with the Debugger next time I get stuck.